# Migrating GIT code base using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I've got a GIT code base that I want to move onto another machine.  I don't want to lose version history and all the rest.  How do I move the entire code base using Eclipse's menu options (and restore it later onto a 2nd machine also running Eclipse)?  Just to emphasize, I'd prefer not to use the command line.

In Eclipse's GIT Repositories view, I see entries in the context menu for "push", "pull", "fetch", etc.  Is this the way to go?  Maybe I have to push from my source machine and fetch into my target machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the .git directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the git repository, you just need to copy it.

As a good practice, you should maintain you repository in a remote location. I use www.assembla.com, it's free.